# What places, or where Can i get a AC transformer that will Increase voltage too 150KV + from household power

Tags: voltage, current, ac, transformer

I am currently in need of locating a Transformer that will step up my household wall power to output in the ballpark between 150kv - 500kv.

Having a bit of a hard time

My project is a table top particle accelerator and the primary need for the device is Ultra High AC voltage

Current Amperes are very low and are not to important so eddy currents and heating hopefully will be manageable.

Comment: the last 75kV generator and 200kV  tripler that I used was pretty old but about 0.5x0.5x1m in size. From the 120Hz ripple and high DC E field even epoxy paint over grounded metal got electrified 5m away causing static arcs and wall railings arced 15 m away every second zap, zap, zap . Do you have any experience with lethal PD or even know what is PD?

Comment: no hands on experience - These test will be done from afar needless to say behind 1.5 feet of lead in a few cases. PD = Potentially Dangerous/Lethal Voltages I would assume but I personally hate acronyms. The particle acceleration has a risk of also being radioactive during operation hence the lead. what kind of precautions have you used in the past?

Comment: X-ray _devices_ are usually anything that emits a broad band of radiation created by collisions into some target. At as much as 500 kV you may not generate much, but you will probably generate some 500 keV gamma along with a whole bunch of softer gamma and x-ray radiation. A typical curve from a 100 kV source looks like: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Basic_Physics_of_Digital_Radiography/The_Source#/media/File:XrtSpectrum.jpg and from that you can see about what you may be in for. Be careful. And that's assuming you don't multiply it further.

Comment: PD is partial discharge a natural , leakage current that builds up high voltage in near perfect insulators and zaps the weakest link followed by the current from the perfect insulator dielectric capacitance discharged from 1/2CV^2 . It is what causes corona on the outside and transformers to explode on the inside and if it happens to discharge to you can be like a discharge from a TV tripler cap that can cause a heart attack. If you do not know how to measure PD or how to measure dust in parts per million in air or your insulator of choice, don't have delusions about managing UHV.

Comment: If you do not know how to measure PD or how to measure dust in parts per million in air or your insulator of choice, don't have delusions about managing UHV. It is what triggers corona on the outside and transformers to explode on the inside and if it happens to discharge to you can be like a discharge from a TV tripler cap that can cause a heart attack.

Comment: If you don't know what causes dielectric absorption which in turn can lead to PD from any imperfect insulator with contaminants in liquid, solid or any gas, you may wish you knew, if you survive after getting zapped. If you don't understand why there is so much arc flash protection gear and know about spontaneous human combustion from improper safety, you might want to learn about PD.

Comment: sorry but your wish is delusional with suitable training.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend three things:

1. Buy the book, "[Exploring Quantum Physics through Hands-on Projects](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118140664)," by David Prutchi and his daughter Shanni Prutchi.
2. You contact the authors of said book immediately and ask for their thoughts about your ideas, thoughts, and wishes -- which to start I assume is a cyclotron with two dees.
3. Go to their web site, perhaps starting here: [DIY 250 kV Power Supply](http://www.diyphysics.com/2012/02/09/d-i-y-250-kv-high-voltage-dc-power-supply-with-neat-trick-for-switching-polarity/). Read carefully through their book and their web site.

A cyclotron is pretty easy by today's standards and there's no reason you can't do it. But I don't think this is the place for a discussion about making one. Not unless you've shown an aptitude for it and are asking specific questions along the way.

---

Just be careful. You casually mentioned Pb (lead), saying you'd sometimes be using 45 cm thickness of it. While at 220 keV, lead is 12 times better stopping power than steel, at 2 MeV it's only 2.5 times better than steel. So don't get too cavalier and imagine that lead is some kind of panacea. It's still mostly vacuum space and you can easily generate gamma radiation that is *very* much smaller than an atomic diameter. The cross-section  (measured in barns) of atoms varies depending the atom and energy of the gamma. You need to be fully aware of these details, and more.

A quick check can be made by looking up "radiographic equivalence factors," often shown in tables that include keV/MeV and materials.

You asked about what a cyclotron is used for. That made me pause a moment. But you can look up a cyclotron on Wiki. But they are used to make short-lived radioisotopes, some cancer treatments, and used to be used for particle physics experiments. Dirt easy to make, these days. Must be plans on the web. (There are also betatrons, linear accelerators, and well.. whatever you can think up, actually.)

Bottom line is that you need to understand ideas of atomic cross section, fully understand different kinds of radiation and how they are generated, and I'd recommend that you have appropriate instrumentation available to monitor what is going on. Not just a Geiger counter. (Which you should have several varieties of.) But also a scintillator capable of differentiating energies -- commonly using NaI(Tl) crystal and a photomultiplier. I designed and built a Geiger counter when I was 16 (and it worked, first time, on a sample of Autunite I had then [still do have that crystal].) So they are very, very easy to understand and design and use. A scintillator is a little more complex. But not that much more so. You should be relatively competent with at least those tools. (There are many more, but probably too expensive unless you are borrowing tools from a lab.)

---

You might also consider joining the Yahoo group called "Geiger Enthusiasts" which is a very active group and a very knowledgeable one. I'd definitely recommend conversing with some of those folks, as well.

Get advice, read, study, learn, test, validate, and enjoy. But don't do this alone. I contacted the designer (a physicist) of a Geiger tube I used (originally just to find out where I could buy his tube) and gained some advice, even as a mere teenager. I also spent days, and weeks, in the science library of the largest university in my State.

So mitigate your risks by getting good information and advice. And if possible, contact your local university and see if someone there may be willing to help (unless you are already involved in one right now -- in which case, why in the heck are you asking these questions here?)

Comment: oh interesting, some of the theoretical applications I have postulated likely apply and or are similar to the Cyclotron. The apparatus is much different though. Just bought the Kindle book just now so will have a gander. What was the purpose of the cyclotron though? thanks again for the resources

Comment: @JoshuaH Just be careful. You mentioned Pb (lead.) At 220 keV, lead is 12 times better stopping power than steel. But at 2 MeV, it's only 2.5 times better than steel. Look up "radiographic equivalence factors" in tables that include keV and materials. You can look up a cyclotron on Wiki. But they are used to make short-lived radioisotopes, some cancer treatments, and used to be used for particle physics experiments. Dirt easy to make, these days. Must be plans on the web.

Comment: Re: HV gen link... One has to use pure alcohol not sold over the counter, approved by NASA to achieve these results in most cases. THis type of solvent has impurities not measured in % but PPM and each particle that can detonate with the kinetic energy proportional to gap squared. If particles accumulates a surface charge , they bridges the gap and then zaps the cloud. This is an example of a sensational publication without the wisdom of safety in mind. PD is the detonation of impurities or voids like a tiny series cap with most of the voltage on the smallest C.

Comment: If you know anyone who has been in contact with an automotive spark will know the reaction can toss oneself like being hit with a sledgehammer with a measly 30kV

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I have been hit by 25-30 kV a few times. Quite memorable.

Comment: Good. then you take my point about UHV safety. But we know it is not the HV that counts but the Joules of stored energy after ignition or detonation of contaminant or capacitor discharge occurs.  Which is also the principle reason how arc welding occurs at low voltage high current supply triggered by a high V low current arc and cardiac discharge machines,

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I'm also experienced doing MIG and SMAW welding! Hehe. I LOVE doing that work, as well, and use it often on my farm, here. (Yes, I have a large acreage.)

Answer (score 3):

To generate UHV successfully and safely you need a lot more than a Marx Generator: You need to understand, imperfect properties of dielectric materials,  E Field gradients and why all insulators are imperfect dielectrics.    Here is a what insulators are needed for safely generating 500kV.[image] Your quest for doing this on a tabletop is like a bug floating down the river asking for the drawbridge to be raised.

Try 50kV before you even think of anything higher. 100kV is possible but unlikely.  e.g small PD arcs within 30m distance from ion streams thru dust in the air can build up this voltage far away. You might need a 1MOhm coated per square Faraday cage and class 100 clean room with e field and PD monitors and a rude awakening on cleanliness and particle counters.

Technicians have been vaporized!! trying to debug 600Vac phases on industrial power panels with a DMM!!  The risk increases with power available after PD escalates to breakdown and then detonation damage by follow-on current from cascaded sources. That is no joke.

[Safety](http://www.electricenergyonline.com/show_article.php?article=157) info.

Comment: The link I gave the OP provides a much, much smaller method for safely generating 250 kV for physics experiments. Take a look at it.

Comment: It's not the size of the generator than counts but the size of the air exposed insulators due to creepage, from ionized particles which accumulate in any home. These 3"  76mm centered "banana" jacks are mounted in a plastic container are lethal weapons at 250kV  under normal invisible conditions of surface residue and moisture absorption of humidity into plastic, would most certainly cause Partial Discharge of pulses every few minutes even at 150kV. Anyone without UHV experience is naive to think otherwise.

Comment: @jonk if you haven't heard of the reality of SHC ( spontaneous human combustion ) in an arc flash, it's no joke.

Comment: I have heard of spontaneous human combustion. It's rare. And I never gave it a lot of thought.

Comment: I've used similar voltage levels in the past, similar to what is on the DIY web site -- order of 300 kV -- without any difficulties at the time and nothing like that monster you showed! But your points about surface conductivity are important. (I used ceramics to penetrate and isolate from a plastic case.) Even the epoxies used in IC packages _leak_ like a sieve -- and much worse if they are not completely clean and pristine. Still, I was able to do table-top physics experiments and I'm still here.

Comment: I've used sulfuric acid in a condensing double boiler arrangement to liquify a normally solid rocket fuel for pouring into a mold, too. It was the only "cheap" and "safe" way to guarantee no "hot spots" that might rise to the flash point of the fuel. But risky. And then there was work with 100% pure insecticides where I had to wear two syringes of atropine in case of exposure. Also used a klystron to irradiate a room (in high school) where we used styrofoam wrapped in tin foil to create a "crystal" and measure diffraction with watt meters, by hand. To learn, one manages risk; not avoid it.

Comment: agreed.   in the early 80's taught myself how to use our Scanning Electron Microscope on ceramic HDD heads with 50kV on a pure insulator in a vacuum chamber creating Stratocumulous charge clouds on the surface appearing white to the TV from electron emissions then turning up the cathode current at 50k x magnification and burning a hole in the thick ceramic. While administering the plant wide ESD program. Most I could generate was 30kV with a 6cm arc using a point discharge after walking with  neoprene shoes on our office nylon carpet during a dry winter.

Comment: that Siemens power transformer with the large donuts at the end of the insulator "bushings" are intended to transfer UHV designed to withstand the environment to reduce the risk of discharge.  I used to climb up on smaller versions of these transformers and connect the  lightning 200kV impulse wire from the tester to look for PD faults in an epidemic factory/field issue.  another risk might be discharges or detonation of SF6 insulating gas turning into mustard gas.  Fuming Gallium Arsenside leaks can kill a stadium full of people with < 1oz

Comment: @Tony re "...  Most I could generate was 30kV ..." -> We used (occasionally :-) ) to create larger storage capacitance by having 6 or so people hold hand an huffle at speed over said carpet to maximise charge generation rate. The frontman (ladies seemed averse to participation) would extend a pointing finger as the shuffling line approached a 'co-victim'. I say "co" as when sark leaped from line of shufflers to target the finger pointer and "mark" both received equal shock and all felt the discharge across he hand-hold connections but at somewhat lesser levels. ...

Comment: kewl.   stimulating electron sharing

Comment: I don't recall if the thought of a possible heart attack triggering occurred to anyone :-(. || FWIW Your use of the term SHC ("spontaneous human combustion") might be better replaced with something along the lines of "Induced ...", but, the point is made! . || SHC is  more usually used for cases where a charred body image is found with no apparent ignition source and limited flame spread. While many such claims are urban legend, there is apparently a mechanism and some case history where a local combustion trigger leads to slow body fat rendering...

Comment: ...  and enough insulation and localised energy concentration to maintain a very slow "tallow candle" effect. Genuine cases probably very rare and hopefully the victim is already dead from other causes.

Comment: recently last year there were cases http://enenews.com/very-significant-explosion-dam-next-nuclear-site-plasma-created-due-tremendous-amount-heat-same-type-phenomenon-lightning-nuclear-sites-fire-department-responds-blast-video.. It is the plasma gas explosion of air that followed the current  from an  HV arc.  I once vaporized the copper end of a bladed screw driver  to pry off a power cable staple carelessly. So my plastic lens glasses had copper vapor condensed like spray paint mist.. after a big bang.